# Express: new Error() is not working outside of server.js/index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a simple custom exception based on [this link](https://rollbar.com/guides/javascript/how-to-throw-exceptions-in-javascript/#) as follows:

```
function userErr(message) {
  logger.info("reach user error function")
  const error = new Error(message);
  error.type = "userErr";
  return error;
}

function failureErr(message) {
  logger.info("reach failure error function")
  const error = new Error(message);
  error.type = "failureErr";
  return error;
}
```

The expected behaviour is Express will throw this error to the custom error handler middleware at the end of the server.js file:

```
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Error Handling Middleware: " + error.message);

  if (error.type === "userErr") {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "error",
      statusCode: "400",
      message: error.message
    });
  } else if (error.type === "failureErr") {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "fail",
      statusCode: "500",
      message: error.message
    });
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "error",
      statusCode: "500",
      message: error.message
    });
  }
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("listening on 8080...");
}); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

When I put these functions above the routes (app.get, app.post, etc...) in the server.js file (this should be index.js for most people), it works fine. But when I start stripping out these routes and put them into a route file in the routes folder instead, the traffic does come to the route correctly, but whenever an error occurs and executes the function above, JavaScript threw an error at the 2nd line, which is:

```
const error = new Error(message);
```

for example:

```
const error = new Error(message);
                ^

Error: [object Object]
    at new failureErr (file:///.../src/server.js:89:17)
    at file:///.../src/routes/testRoutes.js:104:21 {
  type: 'failureErr'
```

Which is weird! I have tried putting these functions into a separate file and importing them into the route file, but it still shows the same error.

I mimicked the folder into the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/express-playground-forked-slu3il?file=/src/index.js:0-1360) (I couldn't manage to make it run) so you can understand the context. The index.js by itself is the one that works, while index2.js with the routers folder is the one that failed.

Appreciate any feedback on the questions, or any ideas on where I did something wrong

Comment: You write "JavaScript threw an error", don't you have a `throw` statement in _your_ code?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Apology, I edited the question just now. It should be throwing an error to the custom error handler middleware instead

Comment: FYI, that rollbar article is over 3 years old and doesn't use the modern way of subclassing the Error object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show in your sandbox is doing this `throw new userError("It's an user error");`, but `userError()` is not properly set up as a constructor and thus can't be called with `new`. This is the code in your sandbox:

```
app.get("/api/v1/test", (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userErr = req.headers.userErr;
    console.log(userErr);
    if (userErr === "true") {
      throw new userError("It's an user error");
    } else {
      throw new failureError("It's an failure error");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});
```

The code you show has not made either `userError()` or `failureError()` into classes or constructors.  They are merely functions.  Therefore, they can't be called with `new`.

If you want to make them into classes, then do something like this:

```
class userError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message);
        console.log("reach user error function");
        this.type = "userErr";
    }
}
```

Note, this is the more modern way of doing this than what is shown in the article you reference (which is apparently old).

Or, you can just use what you have as functions:

```
app.get("/api/v1/test", (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userErr = req.headers.userErr;
    console.log(userErr);
    if (userErr === "true") {
      next(userError("It's an user error"));
      return;
    } else {
      next(failureError("It's an failure error"));
      return;
    }
    res.send("ok");
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried putting next to wrap around userErr/failureErr just now, but it still throws the same error. It's kinda weird cause the function works on the index.js file. My logic was to throw the error, and the catch branch will use next() to send the error to the middleware. Let me try turning the function to classes to see if it works

Comment: @WilliamPham - If this only happens when you try to put things in separate files, then you are probably not importing/exporting things properly so that code defined in one file can be used in another.  Your question doesn't show exactly what your code is so it's hard for us to help more precisely.

Comment: Jackpot! The class works!! Thanks, @jfriend00. Are there any articles where I can read on the modern error handling best practices?

Comment: @WilliamPham - The concepts in that article are fine - their method of creating a subclass of the Error object has been upgraded/replaced with the class I show in my answer.  I don't know of other articles.